# How can I determine which assemblies or using declarations need to be added for WPF classes?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, visual-studio-2013, isolatedstorage

I'm trying to use an IsolatedStorageFileStream based Simon McKenzie's comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310313/is-exiflib-usable-in-a-wpf-xaml-app?noredirect=1#comment41288853_26310313), but adding this code:

```
IsolatedStorageFileStream isfs = null;
```

...gives me, "*The type or namespace name 'IsolatedStorageFileStream' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)*"

I reckon I am (missing a using directive or an assembly reference), but what, exactly? Right-clicking IsolatedStorageFileStream does not give me a "Resolve" option, and adding:

```
using System.IO.IsolatedStorage;
```

...gives me, "*The type or namespace name 'IsolatedStorage' does not exist in the namespace 'System.IO' (are you missing an assembly reference?)*"

Googling for "example of using IsolatedStorageFileStream in wpf" hasn't helped, either.

How can I find out which assembly is needed, or which using is needed?

Comment: On the surface your guess its a missing reference or namespace ambiguity problem seems correct, tell me are you targetting the .Net FULL PROFILE - not the .Net CLIENT PROFILE?

Comment: MSDN docs state which assembly classes are defined in. Just search "Assembly:" on the page to find where it is located. `IsolatedStorageFileStream` is located in `mscorlib.dll` and according to the docs, it is supported in .NET full & client profile (3.5/4). It should be available by default...

Comment: It sounds like one of those err msgs that is masking the problem; the code that caused this err msg was apparently all wrong, and once I redo it, I'm hoping for better results; see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310313/is-exiflib-usable-in-a-wpf-xaml-app/