# Window Phone 8, ExifLib not found

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1, exiflib

I am new on Windows Phone development. I m using **ExifLib** in my code. When i am debug my project it runs good. But when I am trying to release it is always gives my that error, **Error 1   The type or namespace name 'ExifLib' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)**

How can I solve it or release my project?

```
JpegInfo info = ExifReader.ReadJpeg(picturestrem, filename);
```

above line gives me an error on **JpegInfo and ExifReader.ReadJpeg**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you have added `ExifLib.dll` in your release mode. And make sure you have used `namespace`.

```
using Windows.Storage;
using ExifLib;
```

Comment: Yes added certain namespace, but same issue.

Comment: Have you added dll in release? I mean change the `debug` to `release`. Then add `dll` i.e. `ExifLif` to your reference.

Comment: Check in your reference folder of project.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're missing out certain namespace, make sure that you have these `namespaces`:

```
using Windows.Storage;
using ExifLib;
```

Reference:
[Is ExifLib usable in a WPF / XAML app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26310313/)

Comment: Yes added certain namespace, but same issue.